# 2006 Buick rendezvous rpm jump

Tags: rpm, buick

when I drive over 70 my car seems to jump about a quarter of an rpm does not affect speed it's while i travel at a steady speed with cruise on and off plugged in no codes came up checked transmission for leak nothing tried fuel cleaner also didn't help opinions?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Amanda. We all have opinions. This site isn't about opinions. We want to help you, but need more details. Does this happen continuously? Or is it random? When the RPM "jumps", do you feel anything in the vehicle (lurch, stumble, jerk, etc.)? Do you hear a difference in the engine sound?

Answer (score 1):

Huh? You mean at 70 miles per hour, your RPM jumps (say from 2500 RPM to 2500.25 RPM) . How can you even see that?

I suspect you are seeing a 'blip' movement on the RPM needle related to the overdrive lock kicking in.  When the vehicle computer indicates that this high speed travel will be there for awhile, it 'locks' the torque converter into overdrive.  This is typically good for fuel economy, although there might be a momentary change in RPM noticeable by the customer.

It's there to help you save $$.